# Name of matrix which is invariant in trace

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trace, invariant-theory

Let $X$ and $A$ be two real matrices, such that
$$\mbox{tr}(XX^T)=\mbox{tr}(XAX^T),$$
where $A\neq I$.

I like to know any information of matrix $A$ and which matrices $A$ can hold the above equation. Is $A$ some particular matrix?

Comment: You mean $X$ is fixed, and you want to express $A$ as a function of $X$ ?

Comment: $(I-A)$ is orthogonal to $X^T X$... try an eigenvalue decomposition of $X^T X$.

Comment: @user251257 Dou you mean that from $\text{tr}((I-A)XX^T)=0$ follows necessarily orthogonality?

Comment: If $X$ is fixed, it is just a linear equation. The solution space has codimension $1$. It won't get much more exciting.

Answer (score 2):

This answer gives only a sufficient condition.

The equation can be rewritten as $\operatorname{tr}(X^TX)=\operatorname{tr}(AX^TX)$

$\operatorname{tr}(X^TX -AX^TX)=0$
$\operatorname{tr}((I-A) X^TX )=0$

$X^TX$ is a symmetric matrix so it is sufficient that $I-A$ be a skew-symmetric matrix, according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_(linear_algebra)#Other_properties).